# Use Where In with Param

Tags: sql-server

How can I use a param for mulitple values in a "where in" query:

```
Select [..] where str in ('AB','BC')
```

Of course, this will not allow multiple values:

```
Select [..] where str in (@param)
```

Comment: which version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add each param as a value in the IN clause, e.g.

```
where str in (@param1, @param2, @param3)
```

Alternately, you could create a query manually and EXEC it (though that's fraught with peril as well).

EDIT: So, just to clarify, since you're receiving a string of comma-delimited values that you then want to use in an IN clause, you'll need to do what astander suggested and split your string into a table which you could then use in the clause.

Using one of the [links](http://www.logiclabz.com/sql-server/split-function-in-sql-server-to-break-comma-separated-strings-into-table.aspx) astander mentioned you could do the following:

```
select [...]
where str in (select items from dbo.split(@ItemString))
```

(where your comma-delimited values are in @ItemString).

Comment: "You just can't argue with a word like fraught!" Tigger

Comment: I think the OP might intend the params being in the single param such as @param = '''AB'',''BC'''

Comment: Which will _not_ work unless the column contains that exact value (which it shouldn't).

Comment: I think needs a split type function with a select in split function.

Comment: Yes, I need a single param becouse there is a unkown number of values in the array. Is there maybe a way to expand a string like "AB|BC|CD"?

Comment: Check out http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html for an analysis of the many possible split functions. Long, but well worth the read.

Comment: You could use Astander's solution to break the string up into individual rows and add them to a table, then write your query to join this table on the _str_ column. That will give you the results you're looking for (without having to resort to multiple param2 or manually written queries).

Answer (score 3):

The alternative to adding each value as a separate param, if you are using SQL Server 2008, is to pass in a [table valued parameter](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters) which would allow you to do something like:

```
SELECT...
FROM YourTable t
    JOIN @TableParam p ON t.str = p.str
```

If you're not using SQL 2008 and you actually want to pass all the values in as one CSV string, then the other common approach is to have a user defined function that splits the CSV string out and returns a TABLE which you can then join on, e.g.

```
SELECT ....
FROM YourTable t
    JOIN dbo.fnSplit(@param) s ON t.str = s.str
```

Comment: That's nice; wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so you need a split function

[SQL Server split function](https://web.archive.org/web/20200803115239/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/AngelEyes/archive/2007/04/12/111504.aspx)

and

[Split Function in Sql Server to break Comma-Separated Strings into Table](https://web.archive.org/web/20171004145140/http://www.logiclabz.com/sql-server/split-function-in-sql-server-to-break-comma-separated-strings-into-table.aspx)

and

[dbo.Split](https://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=50648)

Comment: Check out http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html for an analysis of the many possible split functions. Long, but well worth the read.